# Where are Laravel controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-artisan

I just started using Laravel. I created a controller with the command:

```
php artisan make:controller WelcomeController
```

Where in the directory structure is this controller. It is not in the app/Http/Controllers folder, where the documetation suggests it would be.

Comment: Did it throw any errors? Also did you type 'php artisan'?  Unless you specify otherwise, they only go in app/Http/Controllets

Comment: That command works fine for me in Laravel 5.1. What version are you using? Did you get any errors or did it say `Controller created successfully.`?

Comment: I didn't get any errors the controller was created successfully.

Comment: Damn, the controllers where acutally created, but eclipse didn't show them until I refreshed the explorer. It was a silly mistake.